# How to return all records only if join in SELECT returns null set

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a list box in a form that is populated by a select query based on another control (ctrl1) in the same form. It is triggered on update of ctrl1:

```
PARAMETERS [Ctrl1 input] Long;
SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2
FROM (table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column2 = table2.column1) INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.column2 = table3.column3
WHERE (((table3.column1)=[Ctrl1 input]))
ORDER BY table1.column2;
```

This works on the basis of the form parameter matching a value in `table3.column1` that ALSO has a value in the `table3.column3` field. Right now, if the selection on the form does not have a matching value in `table3.column3` the list box remains empty. In this situation, I would instead like to return the full list of `SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2` without all the joins and constraints. (The list is very long, so I would only like to use the entire thing when absolutely necessary.)

In SQL, it appears that a `case` function would accomplish what I want, something similar to this:

```
PARAMETERS [Ctrl1 input] Long;
CASE WHEN  (SELECT table3.column3 WHERE (table3.column2 = [Ctrl1 Input]) IS NOT NULL)
    THEN 
        SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2
        FROM (table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column2 = table2.column1) INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.column2 = table3.column3
    ELSE 
        SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2
```

But I'm not able to use `case` in an Access query.

An `IIf` statement seems like it would also work,

```
PARAMETERS [Ctrl1 input] Long;
IIf(
    (SELECT  table3.column3 WHERE (table3.column1 = [Ctrl1 input]) IS NOT NULL),
    (SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2 FROM (table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column2 = table2.column1) INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.column2 = table3.column3),
    (SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2)
    )
```

but Access won't accept that, saying that it expects a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, etc. Also, testing a `SELECT IIf`, I get something saying that it can only return one value, so that doesn't work for me.

SO, I've seen articles for using both `case` and `IIf` in VBA and then using THAT in a query, but I haven't been able to find a clear enough example to understand how I would convert my own situation into a module and then call it. I do not work with VBA, and barely work with SQL. Before delving into VBA I'd like to know:

1. Will I be able to accomplish what I'd like with VBA?
2. Is there a argument for the `case`, `IIf`, or other approach?
3. In the function, what do I pass as the value? The data from ctrl1 on the form?
4. What do I ask the function to return, and how? Is this accomplished by setting `myfunction = the code that produces the dataset I need` within the function itself?

I think I understand how to use the function in the query, so long as I understand the output type from the function.

Thanks in advance for any insight and information.

*Note: I'm using Access 2016 but the file itself is 2002-2003 format because that's apparently what's compatible with our GIS software.*

Comment: IIF() would be correct you are just doing it in the wrong place/order.  The if statement would be used in the WHERE condition of your select not before.  But for that matter you could test it in VBA before calling the sql too.  honestly the code you posted is too jumbled/poorly formated for me to want to try and decode it more but I can see this is at least 1 of your problems

Comment: @Matt How do I address that the `FROM` changes depending on the outcome of the `IIf` if the `FROM` happens before it? 
Apologies for the mess. As I said, I don't know the language. Would it be better if I used generic field and table names? When I look up syntax for each function the examples are very simple and I don't know how to adjust the formatting, not knowing the general SQL approach.

Comment: honestly you should probably test the value and use a VBA if then logic to set the query string and then pass the desired string.  You can do it in sql but you would want to left join your optional table and then use an IF() statement in the JOIN as well as the WHERE to account for when the condition is or is not met.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to have Access not filter something if a control is empty (or no match is found) that doesn't need `IIF` or VBA.  You need to tell Access that if the input is null to just return everything.  Your query at the top would look like this.

```
SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2
    FROM 
        (SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2
        FROM table1 
        INNER JOIN table2 
        ON table1.column2 = table2.column1)
INNER JOIN table3 
ON table1.column2 = table3.column3
    WHERE table3.column1 = [Ctrl1 input]
    OR [Ctrl1 input] is null
ORDER BY table1.column2;
```

The `OR` line is what tells Access "You know what, just give me the whole table if I didn't tell you what to do".  It shouldn't matter how your list box gets populated, this code only cares about what is in the list box, not how it got there. Code like this can just go in the SQL view of an Access query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I use this, I get prompted for values for sq.column1 and sq.column2, and I am not shown any values in the final list, regardless of my selection in the control box. Do I need to store something as "sq" before referencing it? I'm also having syntax problems w
Also, this solution doesn't address the total problem - I'm trying to get the full set of options when a match isn't found between the selection in the box and table 3, not just when the control box is empty.

Comment: Regarding the 'sq' problem, that's a problem with Access not properly processing SQL aliases, which surprises me but is rectified by changing the code to not use the aliases.  I think I can get it to return on non-match by adding `OR table3.column1 != [Crt1 input]`.  I'll edit my answer to cover these changes.

Comment: Scratch that, the `OR table3.column1 != [Ctrl1 input]` is going to return everything no matter what the input has in it (if Access would run the syntax at all).  If you do need it to show everything when there's no match, you probably do need `IIF` and VBA, if it's possible at all.  I don't know how to do that.  I'd advise a design change; have it throw an error if there's no match indicating the process needs a valid value or null.

Comment: Thanks. For the time being I've just hard-coded the exceptions into the `OR` since there are relatively few of them. Not ideal, but I needed to get that whole list even when there weren't matches. Thanks. (I would add that the first `SELECT` above appears to be redundant. This is the same as my initial query with the addition of `OR [crtl1 input] is null`.)

Comment: Yes, it is the same with the `OR` statement added, that's the idea; do the same thing your statement does, or instead return everything.